# Keras seq2seq model Output Shapes

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, seq2seq

I am working on keras seq2seq example here:https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html
What I have understood from the text is in decoder model each cell's output is input to the next cell.
However I didnt understand implementing this recursion to the model.In the link it makes the decoder model as follows.

```
decoder_model = Model(
        [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
        [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

How does this syntax work to tell the model that each cells output is input to next cell?
In general how does this syntax work?

**EDIT**:
When you check keras.Model documentation you will realize that a model can take a  **list** of keras.Input objects as input argument, notice that **[decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs** is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the Keras `Model` class [here](https://keras.io/api/models/model/), you'll see that the `Model()` function takes in `inputs` and `outputs` as its first and second arguments respectively (`Model(inputs, outputs)`). This specifies the input and output layers of the model (in your case, a decoder that will be used in the inference loop of the `decode_sequence()` function at the end of the article you linked).

To elaborate more on the code snippet you posted, you are providing `decoder_inputs` and `decoder_states_inputs` together as the `inputs` argument of `Model(inputs, outputs)` to specify the input layer of the decoder model:

- `decoder_inputs` is an `Input` object (Keras tensor) with length `num_decoder_tokens`, instantiated using the `Input()` function (see [Input](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/)) that simply accepts the input tokens (characters).
- Similarly, `decoder_states_inputs` is a list of two `Input` tensors for the decoder's hidden input state and cell state, both of length `latent_dim`.

And again, you provide the `decoder_outputs` and `decoder_states` together as the `outputs` argument of `Model(inputs, outputs)` to specify the output layer of the model:

- `decoder_outputs` ends up being a densely connected NN layer used for output activation (see [Dense](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/)).
- `decoder_states` is a list containing the hidden state `state_h` and cell state `state_c` of the `decoder_lstm`.